# problem with installing with easy_install on custom python

Tags: python, macos, easy-install, egg

I have a mac osx As such I have the normal python that comes with the machine, and the new version that I have downlaoded, and that works very well. This is in

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
```

Easy_install was only working on the standard version:

```
$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
```

So I downloaded setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg and then

```
$ cd Downloads/
$ sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg 
Password:

Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Adding setuptools 0.6c11 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
```

This seemed to work,

```
$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/easy_install
```

but something is still not working:

```
$ easy_install pymongoSearching for pymongo
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymongo/
Reading http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver
Best match: pymongo 1.9
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pymongo/pymongo-1.9.tar.gz#md5=12e12163e6cc22993808900fb9629252
Processing pymongo-1.9.tar.gz
Running pymongo-1.9/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/vm/vmoE5XqwH-yKiaMzAQS1vE+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-lRHv7W/pymongo-1.9/egg-dist-tmp-xFybXs
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'pymongo'
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from bson/_cbsonmodule.c:23:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from pymongo/_cmessagemodule.c:23:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from bson/_cbsonmodule.c:23:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding pymongo 1.9 to easy-install.pth file
error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth: Permission denied
```

And then when I go on python and I

```
import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth: Permission denied
```

You have to run `easy_install` with root privileges.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. I tried to just su easy install. But it would not work. I had to sudo it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing just : `easy_install pymongo` ??

What would that return when you import pymongo in IDLE?

Comment: Yes, I did this before doing all this. Easy install installs pymongo in python, but not in the version of python that I am using.

Comment: I don't think it is being installed. Look at the error in the last line.

Comment: So when I import pymongo, he would also give me an ImportError

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game, but I had success doing the following on OSX 10.6.7:

```
easy_install pip
```

then:

```
pip install pymongo
```